# How to change the status of switch in ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uiswitch, ant-design-pro

I want to change the status of the switch in ant design

I want the value of the status to be either true when on and false when off

but I am getting true always whether it is on or off

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { UserServices } from '../../services/UserService';
import { Space, Table, Tag, Divider, Skeleton, Switch } from 'antd';
const columns = [
    
    {
        title: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        key: 'phone',
    },
    {
        title: 'Suspended',
        dataIndex: 'suspended',
        key: 'suspended',
```

Here I tried to switch between on and off

```
        render: (status, suspended) => {
            return (
                <>

                    <Switch onChange={() => handleSwitchChange(status)} />
                </>
            )
        }

    },
]
```

Here I am trying to get the value of the switch and negate(get the opposite) of the switch status

```
const handleSwitchChange = (value) => {
    value = !value
}

const staff = () => {

    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await UserServices.getStaff();
            setDataSource(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <h3>Staffs</h3>
            <Divider />
            {dataSource ? <Table scroll={{ x: 400 }} className="table-striped-rows" columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} /> : <Skeleton active />}
        </>
    )
}

export default staff
```

Comment: I think you are missing something, can you add full code?

Comment: You need to update state for switch value, If you want i will create switch demo then you will use it as per your requirement in your component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'antd';

const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(false);

  const asyncData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      phone: '1234567890',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      phone: '1234567890',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      phone: '1234567890',
    },

  ]

  useEffect(() => {
    const tempData = asyncData.map((item) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        status: false,
      }
    })
    setData(tempData);
  }, []);
  
  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'status',
      key: 'name',
      render: (status, record) => (
        <Switch
          checked={status}
          onChange={() => {
            const tempData = data.map((item) => {
              if (item.id === record.id) {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  status: !item.status,
                }
              }
              return item;
            })
            setData(tempData);
          }} 
        /> 
      ),
    }
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

You should keep track of which row you checked with Switch component by keeping it in the dataSource and update it accordingly. Here is an example, you can adapt it to your code or i can provide further information in the comments.